# Go back to last url containing string

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I want to create an `ActionBar` for my `WebView` application, which should appear, as soon, as the user leaves the original site, which contains a link back to the last page, the user visited on the original site.

For example:

The startpage of the app is: `https://example.com/`
If the user clicks on an external link on `https://example.com/blog/article/`, i want to provide him a link right back there, and not to the startpage. Even if he has allready clicked multible links afterwards.

i tried it with a while loop, but it crashes my app:

```
String webUrl = view.getUrl();
            while (!webUrl.contains("https://bewusstewelt.")) {
                view.goBack();
            }
```

Is there something like "Go back to last url containing string "example.com"?

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) to detect every URL changes on your WebViewClient. Once your URL will change you will get to know and you can redirect your user to original page.You can refer this [example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
This is not exactly, what i am looking for, i specified the question and added an example, maybe it is clearer that way.

Comment: You should not click them, the links are the example.